# Error "Asp.net 4.0 has not been registered on the webserver you need to manually configure your webserver" while adding new project in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I got error

> Asp.net 4.0 has not been registered on the webserver you need to
>   manually configure your webserver

while adding new project in visual studio 2012, I already have register asp.net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

This should solved the problem

Run the command prompt "`As Administrator`". Copy following command to command prompt :

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i

If this doesn't solve the problem then try following :

**Manually configure your Web server for ASP.NET 4.0 :**

Make sure the IIS feature is turned on with ASP.NET. Go to Control Panel > **Programs and Features** > then click 'Turn Windows Featrues on. Find Internet Information Service > WWW servers > App Dev Features, make sure that ASP.NET is checked.

[image]

Then try again : Run the command prompt "`As Administrator`". Copy following command to command prompt :

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i

This solutions will work,.. good luck (y)